# confluence going to incorrect URL

Tags: confluence

I tried to modify the ./confluence/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xmlq

in an attampt to redirect conflunece from the base URL '/' to the '/confluence' URL.

I modified the following lines:

```
<from>/images/icons/attachments/file.gif</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect">%{context-     path}/images/icons/contenttypes/attachment_16.png</to>
```

To say:

```
<from>/</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect">%{context-path}/confluence</to>
```

And NOW what the url

for Confluence stays at this URL which doesn't work.

```
http://confluence.mycompany.com/confluence.bravotv.com/confluence
```

Even after reverting the change to urlrewrite.xml from the saved back up and bouncing confluence. It still persist at that broken URL. How do I get confluence to forget the broken URL and use the one it was using before? Is there some cache that needs to be flushed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working with the issue of Confluence prefixing a Web Link with the Server Base URL when utilising a relative path; the support call that was raised basically boiled down to:
"Unfortunately, on further research I could then confirm that there're no known workaround or an automated way of performing this [keeping a relative URL] and it can only be achieved manually as what you've mentioned."

To resolve the issue, I have written a sed script that post-processes and exported XML backup of the Space.  When imported, Confluence keeps the relative path and it works fine (as long as you don't edit it).

I hope this helps.

Comment: This has been raised as an improvement at CONF-29021at https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-29021 which you can vote on.